# Como pegar o item do *ngFor Angular 7

Tags: c#, html, angular, typescript, select

Pessoal eu tenho um select onde eu seleciono uma empresa

```html
 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <select class="form-control" name="Empresa" formControlName="Empresa">
        <option selected value="null">Selecione a Empresa</option>
        <option *ngFor="let empresa of Empresa; let i= index;">{{empresa.nomeFantasia}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

e quando eu Salvo essa Label com o nome da empresa, eu deveria de pegar a UF desta empresa para fazer uma validação mas ela não está sendo pega, então o save no typescript está assim

```html
    const empresa = this.form.get('Empresa').value;
    if (empresa === null) {
      this.servicesMessages.notification.exibirMensagemDeErro('A Empresa não foi informada');
      return;
    }
```

eu pensei em fazer algo mais ou menos neste nível

```html
    if (empresa.uf) {
        
    }
```

mas ele só pega o nome da empresa que foi setado, já tentei criar um Model, mas eu não consigo passar o index, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza assim com base [neste exemplo](https://medium.com/@kastepanyan24/how-to-set-selected-option-dynamically-in-angular-6-85c99958cca5).

**HTML**

```
<!-- Form starts -->
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="controlEmpresa">
       <option selected [value]="null">Selecione a Empresa</option>
       <option *ngFor="let emp of Empresa;" [value]="emp.nomeFantasia">{{emp.nomeFantasia}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <!-- Form ends -->
```

**Registar ReativeForms no @NgModule no app.module.ts**

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  // ...
})

export class AppComponent {

  empresaForm = this.fb.group({
    controlEmpresa: ['']
  });

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  onSubmit() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.empresaForm.value))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você chama `const empresa = this.form.get('Empresa').value;` o valor que está sendo buscado é a propriedade `value` do campo option. Como essa propriedade está nula, o valor passado está sendo o valor que está entre as tags option, ou seja, o valor `{{empresa.nomeFantasia}}`.

Para resolver seu problema, sugiro que passe o objeto completo como value:`value="empresa"`:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <select class="form-control" name="Empresa" formControlName="Empresa">
        <option selected value="null">Selecione a Empresa</option>
        <option *ngFor="let empresa of Empresa; let i= index;" value="empresa">{{empresa.nomeFantasia}}</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

E sugiro também que chame a variável Empresa de empresas e tira o index que não está sendo usado.

```
<option *ngFor="let empresa of empresas" value="empresa">{{empresa.nomeFantasia}}</option>
```

Aí isso aqui passa a funcionar:

```
if (empresa.uf) {
        // código aqui
    }
```